# Rails: Display image from nested attribute in edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, nested-forms

I'm using Rails, Mongoid and carrier wave.

Here is the code I'm using.

**page.rb**

```
class Page
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    embeds_many :pictures

    attr_accessible :picture_image, :picture_image_cache, :picture_title
end
```

**picture.rb**

```
class Picture
    include Mongoid::Document
    mount_uploader :picture_image, Picture_imageUploader

    embedded_in :page 

    field :picture_image, :type => String
    field :picture_title, :type => String
end
```

**form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for(@page) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :pictures do |f| %>
        <!-- This is a nested form -->

        <!-- Preview of previously uploaded picture -->
        <% @page.pictures.each do |picture| %>
            <%= image_tag picture.picture_image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
        <% end %>

        <!-- Upload button -->
        <%= f.input :picture_image, :as => :file, :label => 'Choose an Image:'%>

        <!-- Title for picture -->
        <%= f.input :picture_title, :label => 'Picture Title:'%>

         <%= f.link_to_remove "Delete this item" %>

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In the edit form - I want to show a preview of a previously uploaded image just above the "upload new image" button. The code above worked except that it loops (obviously) and displays all of the images in each section. For example, if I have 3 entries of "pictures" it will show all three pictures above each of the "upload" buttons.

I only want it to show the relevant image for that specific entry. I would imagine something like this would work `<%= image_tag @page.picture_image_url(:thumb).to_s %>` but it doesn't.

What simple, silly mistake am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked but with a `embeds_many :pictures` the relation for your loop must be:

```
<% @page.pictures.each do |picture| %>
  .
  .
  .
 <% end %>
```

If I understand what you want to do and you want show only 1 image on your loop, you can try:

```
<% for picture in @page.pictures.limit(1).shuffle %>
 .
 .
 .
<% end %>
```

Try with this code!

Comment: hey..thanks for the follow up. So that code limits just limits the loop to the first on. Let's say I have three entries, all three of them are showing the same picture now - not each separate specific image.

Comment: You can add `.shuffle` for random, but this does not mean that the images are not to be repeated.

Comment: I don't want random images - I want them to be associated with the appropriate entry in the form.

Comment: you are speaking of `entry object` you refer to `page object` object?